# Render a layout in a helper class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm rendering the following html fragment...

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <%= yield %>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

... like this:

```
<%= render :layout => "shared/menu" do %>
    ...code here...
<% end %>
```

Now in order to clean up things even more, I'd like to hide the render in a helper, in order to have something like:

```
<%= bs_menu do %>
    ...code here...
<% end %>
```

I've tried without success the following helper:

```
def bs_menu(&block)
    render(:layout => "shared/menu") &block
end
```

I get this error from rails (3.2.1):

> You invoked render but did not give any of :partial, :template,
>   :inline, :file or :text option.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can also do this:

```
def bs_menu(&block)
  render({:layout => "shared/menu"}, &block)
end
```

(Maybe you can also ommit the curly braces). This is a my standard way of passing blocks to methods.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found out how to write the helper. I was not calling the block correctly:

```
def bs_menu(&block)
    render(:layout => "shared/menu") do
        block.call
    end
end
```

I think that's a really neat way to write clean views. Another option is something like [this](http://www.igvita.com/2007/03/15/block-helpers-and-dry-views-in-rails/).